# How can I set multiple object properties simultaneously with CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript, associative-array

```
      dbLocation[latitude] = data[1]
      dbLocation[longitude] = data[2]
      dbLocation[locationText] = locationText
```

That's my `CoffeeScript`, any way to optimize it so it's more condensed?

Comment: Hm, in JavaScript there is `Object.defineProperties`...

Comment: You would have to write the name of the object - `dbLocation` in this case - only once (instead of for example three times as in your code).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; it's a perfectly legitimate question. (Note: I took the liberty of making the title more accurate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
obj = {
  latitude: data[1]
  longitude: data[2]
  locationText
}
```

and then merge that new object in to `dbLocation` by writing

```
dbLocation[key] = val for key, val of obj
```

or using a function like jQuery or Underscore's `extend`.

Comment: There's no way to do this in one step?

Comment: Not without a helper function. If you're using Underscore.js: `_.extend dbLocation, {latitude: data[1], longitude: data[2], locationText}`. If you're using jQuery, use `$.extend` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner, but it's not really much more readable:

```
[dbLocation.latitude, dbLocation.longitude, dbLocation.locationText] = [data[1], data[2], locationText]
```